# Python numpy : Sum an array selectively given information from a second array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say I have a N-dimensionnal array, for example:

```
A = [ [ 1, 2] ,
    [6, 10] ]
```

and another array B that defines an index associated with each value of A

```
B = [[0, 1], [1, 0]]
```

And I want to obtain a 1D list or array that for each index contains the sum of the values of A associated with that index. For our example, we would want

```
C = [11, 8]
```

Is there a way to do this efficiently, without looping over the arrays manually ?

Edit: To make it clearer what I want, if we now take A the same and B equal to :

B = [[1, 1], [1,1]]

Then I want all the values of A to sum into the index 1 of C, which yields

C = [0, 19]

Or I can write a code snippet :

```
C = np.zeros(np.max(B))
for i in range(...):
   for j in range(...):
      C[B[i,j]] += A[i,j]
return C
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the best answer for now actually.

I can just use:

```
np.histogram(B, weights = A)
```

This code provides the solution I want.